# Changing button value based on toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What I want to do is to make the button value to be "1" if the section opened by pressing it is visible, and make it show "2" if the section is not visible. (visible/not visible - hidden/visible).

Here is my failed attempt that I think got the closest to the truth:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".doc1").hide();
    $(".doc").click(function(){
        $(".doc1").slideToggle("fast");

        if($('.doc1').is(':visible')) {
            document.getElementById('doc').value = '1';
        }
        else
            document.getElementById('doc').value = '2';
    });
});
```

The value is stuck on "2" whether the section is opened (visible) or hidden (.hide).

Comment: Can you post the HTML layout too? First you use "doc" as a class name $(".doc") and then as an element id document.getElementById('doc'). That seems wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to use jquery, continue to use it through out. Makes it much easier to go back and fix/read.

Below might be what you are looking for.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".doc1").hide();
    $(".doc").click(function(){
        $(".doc1").slideToggle("fast", function() {
           if($(this).is(':visible')) {
              $('#doc').val('1');
           } else {
              $('#doc').val('2');
           }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: This works as well, and this is what I'm going to use due to the reasons you mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple things.  First you have `$(".doc").click`.  Do you mean `$("#doc").click`?

Secondly, if you start the animation before you check `:visible`, it will *always* be considered visible.  You either need to make the value change the callback of the `slideToggle` call, or just reverse the assignment order and do `slideToggle` afterwards:

http://jsfiddle.net/95nKw/

Answer (score 2):

According to jquery documentation:

**During animations that hide an element, the element is considered to be visible until the end of the animation. During animations to show an element, the element is considered to be visible at the start at the animation.**

May be you should wait until the animation is completed

```
$(".doc").click(function(){
    $(".doc1").slideToggle("fast", function(){
        if($('.doc1').is(':visible')) {
            document.getElementById('doc').value = '1';
        }
        else
            document.getElementById('doc').value = '2';     
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, but i would try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".doc1").hide();
    $(".doc").click(function(){
        $(".doc1").slideToggle("fast");

        if($('.doc1').is(':visible')) {

             $(".doc").val("1");  //or .val(1);
        }
        else
             $(".doc").val("2");
    });
});
```

Comment: Try to ensure that what you are posting will work. What you have posted is nearly identical to the original question.

Comment: $(".doc").val("1");  is not identical to  document.getElementById('doc').value = '1';

Comment: What you have is nearly identical, and will still not work. Also, you are attempting to get an element by class and change its value. The original is trying to get an element by id and change its value. Also, you if else structure will not work.